# Angular ngAfterContentInit : what content are we talking about

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand in details the lifecycle hook of Angular and I am struggling understanding ngAfterContentInit.

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after Angular has completed initialization of all of the directive's content. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

What directive "content" are we talking about exactly ? Can someone explain me and provide me some examples ?

Comment: Why not experiment for yourself? Set up a series of nested components and put some console logging in there to see when ngOnInit(), ngAfterContentInit(), etc run?

Comment: Content is what is passed as child and projected into the component using `ng-content` directive. Here is the official [example](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#aftercontent). When you do follow-up search, search the "ng-content" and everything will be clear to you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `afterContentInit` function gets called when the external component content has been initialized (Careful, initialized! Not rendered).

As  [the doc reports](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) :

> The AfterContent sample explores the AfterContentInit() and
>   AfterContentChecked() hooks that Angular calls after Angular projects
>   external content into the component.

After firing the `AfterContentInit()` Angular will fire another callback: `AfterContentChecked()`. This life-cycle is being fired after Angular has finished checking all the component's reference stuff (Input, Output, DI, and so on).